# In pagerSlidindTabStrip text display incomplete for Moto G 4+ android 7

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, pagerslidingtabstrip

In my project I have used PagerSlidingTabStrip library .now in all other device it display proper text in PagerSlidingTabStrip . but in Moto G 4+ it displays incomplete text in PagerSlidingTabStrip. like it display only "Entertain” instead "Entertainment” . what need to change, plz help me. Thanks In advance.

```
 <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/VideoTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
        android:paddingLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:pstsActivateTextColor="@color/white"
        app:pstsDeactivateTextColor="@color/white"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@color/toolbar_color"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:pstsTabBackground="@color/toolbar_color"
        app:pstsTextAllCaps="false"
        app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivNextFragment"/>
```

**In java file**

```
   public void init(View rootview) {
      tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) rootview.findViewById(R.id.VideoTabs);
      mTabsLinearLayout = ((LinearLayout) tabs.getChildAt(0));

      pager = (ViewPager) rootview.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
     //        tabs.setShouldExpand(true);
     pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(listPublisherName.size());

     setupViewPager(pager);
     tabs.setViewPager(pager);
     tabs.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     pager.setCurrentItem(0);
     tabs.setTabSwitch(true);

     TextView tv = (TextView) mTabsLinearLayout.getChildAt(pos);
     tv.setTextSize(16);
     tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
   }
```

screen is like this right now[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing some changes in code, it will work right now perfect. may be it help some one in future so post here changes.I made changes in xml file as below.

```
 app:pstsShouldExpand="false"
```

It will work fine .

Answer (score 0):

add tabs.setDistributeEvenly(false);

Comment: this property is not available in PagerSlidingTabStripLibrary.